# Обновление данных в GridView

Tags: android

Раньше обновлял `ListView` после изменения данных так:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Все обновлялось и корректно работало.

Но сейчас я использую `GridView` и данные должны вводиться через диалог, по нажатию кнопки в диалоге добавляться в БД, а `GridView` после того, как с экрана пропадет диалог(`DialogFragment`) должен  сразу отображать изменения.

Но так не происходит, а изменения отображаются только после перезапуска программы.

Как можно сделать так, чтоб данные в `GridView` обновлялись - когда мне нужно?

Comment: А под дебагом смотрели ли? после закрытия Dialog-a в onResume() заходит?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, нет, почему то не заходит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил вызывая где надо `onPause` и `onResum` методы фрагмента!

Проблема была из за  того, что фрагмент вызывал `DialogFragment` и не приостанавливался соответственно после завершения работы диалога не вызывался `onResume` где и проходило обновление!